# How to access docker container listening on 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am new to Docker and trying to run an open-source Django application with Docker Desktop for Windows.

Command `docker container ls` shows the application is running, and the service is listening on port `0.0.0.0:8000`.

What IP address should I use on the Windows host to access this service? I appreciate your help.

```
docker container ls

...
1f2c70d56d48   saleor-platform_api          "python manage.py ru…"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
                                                               saleor-platform-api-1
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see here:

> 0.0.0.0:8000->8000

Docker is mapping the port 8000 of your container to the port 8000 of the host. Therefore, to send a request to the container, you need to make a request to `localhost:8000` from the host (Windows in your case).

Comment: Thank you, @Tedpac.  The mapping part is an especially useful background introduction to me.

Answer (score 1):

You would use port 8000 and host as either localhost or 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0.